# Procedure with Exception Handling

Tags: oracle, exception, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-insert

Create a PL/SQL Procedure to insert employee details into Employee table. Before inserting, check whether the employee age is eligible or not.  Employee age should be 18 or greater.  Values are passed as argument to the procedure.

If age valid, insert employee record into table and print the message "Age valid - Record inserted", else print the message "Age invalid - Record not inserted" by raising an exception.

[image]

```
coding:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_AGE_ELIGIBILITY(
v_id IN EMPLOYEE.EMPID%TYPE, 
v_name IN EMPLOYEE.EMPNAME%TYPE, 
v_age IN EMPLOYEE.AGE%TYPE)AS
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Employee(EMPID,EMPNAME,AGE)Values(103,'Robert',24);
select age from Employee;
IF AGE >=18
dbms_output.put_line('Age valid -Record inserted');
else
dbms_output.put_line('Age invalid -Record not inserted');
END; 
/

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
Age valid -Record inserted
```

Comment: This looks like homework to me, so I will just give you some hints. `103,'Robert',24` are hardcoded values, your procedure should use the variables you define v_id, v_age...etc.
You should check the eligibility on the age variable as well and only do the insert on the branch that allows it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to check first, then insert if the check succeds (while your code is doing things the other way around). I also fixed the syntax of your  `if` statement, and changed the `insert` statement so it uses the procedure arguments instead of hardcoded values. Finally, if you want to raise an error, then use `raison_application_error()` rather than `put_line()`.

This should do what you want:

```
create or replace procedure check_age_eligibility(
    v_id in employee.empid%type, 
    v_name in employee.empname%type, 
    v_age in employee.age%type
)
as
begin 
    if v_age >=18 then
        insert into employee(empid,empname,age)values(v_id, v_name, v_age);
        dbms_output.put_line('age valid -record inserted');
    else
        raise_application_error( -20001, 'age invalid - record not inserted' );
    end if;
end; 
/
```

Although this might not be what you were asked to do, please note that you don't need a procedure for this. You can just use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table employee add constraint age_above_18 check(age >= 18);
```

You can then use regular `insert` statements to feed the table - an error is raised for each row that conflicts with the constraint.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32b42e4d279cc55fd33547c1826b7e7c)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the user-defined exception. declare it inside the procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CHECK_AGE_ELIGIBILITY(
    v_id IN EMPLOYEE.EMPID%TYPE,
    v_name IN EMPLOYEE.EMPNAME%TYPE, 
    v_age IN EMPLOYEE.AGE%TYPE) as

not_of_age exception;

    begin
        if v_age>=18 then
            insert into EMPLOYEE(empid,empname,age) values(v_age,v_name,v_age);
            dbms_output.put_line('Age valid - Record inserted');
        else
            raise not_of_age;

        end if;
    exception
        when not_of_age then
        dbms_output.put_line('Age invalid - Record not inserted');
end;
/
```